# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<302> itShouldAllowAccessToSecuredPageForPermittedUser

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

My tomcat application is refusing to build when I try to launch it on tomcat on the following errors

```
Tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 13.603 sec <<< FAILURE!
itShouldAllowAccessToSecuredPageForPermittedUser(ie.claddino.chat.LoginTestCase)  Time elapsed: 12.791 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<302>
```

This is the method that is failing from controller class

```
@Test
    public void itShouldAllowAccessToSecuredPageForPermittedUser() throws Exception {
        SecurityContext securityContext = userAuthentication();
        MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
        session.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, securityContext);
        mockMvc.perform(get(SECURED_URI).session(session))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(redirectedUrl(LOGIN_PAGE_URL));
    }*
```

Please what could be wrong with my application? Please does anyone know what status 302 means.

Comment: This may be helpful.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357518/spring-security-3-always-return-error-302?rq=1 and about 302 status (https://httpstatuses.com/302).

Answer (score 0):

302 means temporary redirecting request. When there is url redirect to be completed, we can do it using a `302` status code and having the url as a parameter in the header.

Since you are doing a redirection, I think you should expect a 302 response as well. `status().isOk()` means `200` status code. Check is there any method for temporary redirect or just put 302 there. hence it can check for 302 code instead of 200.