# Spring security authentication returns 302

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I cant login with spring security. It returns `302`. 
For example on the root I've got links to other pages. If I want to somewhere Spring gives me login form. But I can't do anything with it. Its look like its being refreshing any time when I press the submit button with correctly name and pass or without.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcAHj.png) of response.

**MvcConfig.class**

```
   @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }

        @Bean
        @Override
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            UserDetails user =
                    User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                            .username("user")
                            .password("password")
                            .roles("USER")
                            .build();

            return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
        }
   }
```

I've got registered paths `/` and `/login`

**MvcConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("root");
    }
}
```

**login.mustache**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>
Login page
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
<a href="/registration">Add new user</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-serving-web-content</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357518/spring-security-3-always-return-error-302

Comment: @moilejter I read it, but didnt find anything that would help

Comment: @EnzyWeiss I think you forgot to define SuccessHandler

Comment: @SukhpalSingh Why Spring [lesson](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) does not say about it? Everything works there.

Comment: @SukhpalSingh  I added SuccessHandler but still nothing

Comment: @EnzyWeiss Can you show us? I don't see any other page in your code

Comment: @EnzyWeiss What password encoder do you use?